# Echo content of h1 by id

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, echo

I'm working on a custom wordpress theme and trying to make a scrolltoanchor menubar.
With a plug-in I installed, the user can give custom id to the titles he creates (ex. #title1 for the first one, etc.). The scrolling works but I'm trying to get the content of each h1 (of which I know the id) to echo it in the menu...
I tried this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('menu1').innerHTML = "<?php echo $menu1; ?>" ;
</script>
```

And then echo it in the menubar

```
<div class"menubar">
   <h3><a href="#menu1"><?php echo $menu1; ?></a></h3>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work. It removes the content from the h1 and doesn't return anything ...
Am I doing this all wrong ?
Anybody can help ?

Comment: Does the `$menu1` variable have any value?

Comment: Actually I just realised that it doesn't. I think this goes way over my head, I'm really not used to php. My concern is actually giving the content of the h1 as a value to the variable ...

Comment: Why are you not using an id-property? Like <a href="#menu1" id="menu1"><?php echo $menu1; ?></a>

Comment: I don't need the item in the menubar to have that id, I need it to display the text of the h1 that has the id #menu1. Don't know if it's clear ...